# upload xamarin forms project to app store and playstore

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, app-store

I have xamarin project that someone developed it , and my task is to upload this project to appstore and play store .
i just have an **Apple Developer Account** and **Apple ID Account**
i saw this link according appstore in xamarin documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/itunesconnect/
but i don't know if it's missing something or no or if this is the right link to follow !!
could anyone help me how to do this task step by step or any link that support that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have found the Xamarin walkthrough that is the correct process for publishing to the Apple App Store.

There are a lot of steps and you have to follow them carefully.

The Android process is a lot simpler and [can be found here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/)